# How do you float an image in html?

Tags: html

Simple question: How do you float an image without having it stick to the far left, or far right?

Whenever I use float:left - it just sticks completely on the left side.

I tried using margin, but that just makes the object bigger and messes up the layout for other objects.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide code sample or js fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/vw52e/1/

The youtube video is completely stuck to the left :\

I would like to move it more inside the page, but not completely in the center.

Comment: Check my answer. If it works for you, please be sure to ACCEPT, so future questions you may have will be answered. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Margin doesnt or padding does not make the "object" bigger. It affects the box-model of the object by adding, for want of a better term, white space to where you have applied the margin. From you various comments it sounds like you are trying to have text on all sides of the object

Comment: Have you looked for float tutorials on line... try: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ or http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101. Also look at `display:inline-block` as an alternative to floats

Comment: Also worth a look...http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Put a set width on the containing box so the size wont change, then float the image left with margin?

Comment: I tried using margin or padding, but it just makes the element bigger, and then I can't put anything around it or near it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-left: 20px;` to `.youtube`. Set it to whatever value you like:

```
.youtube {
    margin-left: 20px; /* set to whatever value you choose */
    float: left;
    height: 360px;
    width: 640px;
    clear:both;
}
```

***Side note***, a lot of your HTML was broken. For example, missing `</header>` closing tag, your `<img />` tag wasn't closed properly, and you were also missing `</div>` closing tags.

In addition, as for W3C standards, you shouldn't have a `div` within a `li` tag (I didn't fix this). Use a `<span>` instead and set it to `display:block` if you need it to perform like a `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vw52e/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike.

The problem is adding a margin makes the element bigger, doesn't it? Is there a way to avoid that, or is that the normal way of putting things on a web page? In the end it just seems to push other things out of the way, so it's not very practical..

Comment: It doesn't make the element bigger. It just moves it over by the amount you set. Not sure what your saying it's pushing over. There's no code after the video.

Comment: To be honest with you (take no offence), but the code you have is not very well written. So your issue probably steams somewhere else. In other words, seems like you still have a ways to go before this site is "functional".

Comment: I updated it here with what I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/vw52e/4/

I'm trying to put that text on the right of the video (not  too close, but not too far).

If you inspect the element or try to highlight the text, it highlights a lot of space because of the margin.

Edit: none taken. I've only been at this for 3 days, so trying my  best :)

Comment: Dude...there's so many errors in your code and the CSS is quite bad. See all the bright red HTML tags in your jsFiddle? Those are errors because you haven't closed the tags properly. As for your CSS, your menu `li` and other elements are a complete mess. You're also missing closing CSS tags here as well. Read a couple more tutorials on building basic websites to get you started. Work from there...